# Is there a way to disable video rendering in OpenAI gym while still recording it?

Tags: video, openai-gym

Is there a way to disable video rendering in OpenAI gym while still recording it?

When I use the atari environments and the `Monitor` wrapper, the default behavior is to not render the video (the video is still recorded and saved to disk). However in simple environments such as `MountainCarContinuous-v0`, `CartPole-v0`, `Pendulum-v0`, rendering the video is the default behavior and I cannot find how to disable it (I still want to save it to disk).

I am running my jobs on a server and the officially suggested workaround with `xvfb` does not work. I saw that a lot of people had problems with it as it clashes with nvidia drivers. The most common solution I found was to reinstall nvidia drivers, which I cannot do as I do not have root access over the server.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you have **video_callable=False** kwarg in gym.wrappers.Monitor()

```
import gym

from gym import wrappers

env = gym.make(env_name) # env_name = "Pendulum-v0"

env = wrappers.Monitor(env, aigym_path, video_callable=False ,force=True)
```

then you wish to use

```
s = env.reset() # do this for initial time-step of each episode
s_next, reward, done = env.step(a) # do this for every time-step with action 'a'
```

to run your episodes

Comment: `NameError: name 'aigym_path' is not defined`

Comment: aigym_path is a directory you wish to save the videos rendered UNLESS you set the 'video_callable' being False. Give it a string of directory sth like '/home/<your home dir name>/bla/bla/savedFilms'

Answer (score 1):

Call this function before calling `env.render()`, since rendering is not imported before your first `render()` call, and this function will replace the default viewer constructor.

```
def disable_view_window():
    from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering
    org_constructor = rendering.Viewer.__init__

    def constructor(self, *args, **kwargs):
        org_constructor(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.window.set_visible(visible=False)

    rendering.Viewer.__init__ = constructor
```